# Set up input element as trigger mailchimp form

Tags: dom-events, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up a click listener on the marked input element in the screenshot wit GTM. When I click on it in the preview & debug mode it only returns `gtm.element:object` HTMLInputElemtent. Also form listener doesn't work for this element. Since there is no id, class etc. I have no clue how to deal with that.

Does anyone know how I can access this element and set it as as trigger on click.

[image: MailChimp for Wordpress]

Comment: Did you try a DOM type variable set to CSS selector with an attribute selector expression (e.g. input[type="submit"]) ? Then extract the name (via the "attribute name" field) and use in combination with a click event in your trigger.

Comment: You mean this way?function(){
  var s = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
  return s.name; 
} input has no name so I only get an empty string.

Comment: There is a variable type "DOM element" which can be set to accept a css selector, and return the value of an attribute. So while your suggestion should work as well there should be no need for custom javascript.